# metadata generation failed in pygame installation

Tags: python

when I try to install pygame from command line why does it show

> metadata generation failed

and

> setup.py not found

I have tried using `pip install pygame`
`pip3 install pygame`

I have tried almost all the codes but still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Pygame isn't updated for new versions of python, but you can still install a pre-version with `pip install pygame --pre`